# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'datepicker'

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to use jQuery Datepicker in my website. However when I use the same I get the following error.
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'datepicker'
I've googled on this for quite sometime. All of these say that the problem could be due to loading jquery twice. I have checked and this isn't the case.
I load the jQuery scripts in the following way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxx/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxx/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxx/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxx/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js"></script>
...
...
<input type="text" id="arrival-date-10">
<input type="text" id="departure-dat-14">
....
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#arrival-date-10").datepicker();
    $("#departure-date-14").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

I get the error in line $("#arrival-date-10").datepicker();

Please can someone help me?

Partha

Comment: What happens if you use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` instead?

Comment: JS questions are not on-topic for this site. That said, you've already received plenty of useful answers below (and one spot-on in the comment above this one).

Answer (score 1):

This line shouldn't be in there:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xxxx/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

In a standard WordPress install, no such file exists. This makes me wonder how you are adding the scripts to the theme in the first place. Are you using `wp_enqueue_styles`? If not, there is a VERY good chance that you are indeed adding two versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having a jQuery conflict.  Give it a try in noconflict mode like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#arrival-date-10").datepicker();
    $("#departure-date-14").datepicker();
});
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

I wonder if this wouldn't be better asked on Stack Overflow instead, it's not really a WordPress question (unless you're asking how to properly enqueue scripts).